# Clarification on sqlTransaction operations

Tags: c#, sql

My understanding of a transaction is that it is one or multiple SQL commands that will all be executed as a group.

Now, I'm reading [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#examples) and I do not understand the goal of the first `try-catch` exception block. Why would we try to rollback the transaction if it fails. What I mean is that if it fails, then shouldn't we be positive that no changes were done in the DB (since that's the goal of a transaction) ? What am I not understanding ?

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;

        // Start a local transaction.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

        // Must assign both transaction object and connection
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Logging exception details
            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // Logging exception details
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First TRY...CATCH: A problem occurs in first command, you must have a CATCH to handle the Rollback.
Second TRY...CATCH: Exception is not SO relevant here, but you dont want to break everything when you cannot rollback. Some people discard exception "ex2" (I don't !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#examples) that you linked: "The transaction is rolled back on any error, *or if it is disposed without first being committed*." [My emphasis]. So I would expect the following to work too:

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        using (SqlTransaction transaction connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction"))
        {
            // Must assign both transaction object and connection
            // to Command object for a pending local transaction
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is no explicit Rollback call here.

Because I have put the SqlTransaction into a using a block, it will always get disposed, *even if an exception is thrown*. If execution proceeds normally, the "transaction.Commit()" will commit the transaction. However, if an exception is thrown and we don't get to the Commit() call, then the transaction won't be committed, but it will still be disposed (on leaving the scope of the using block). And we know from the documentation that the transaction will be rolled back if it is disposed without first being committed, or indeed, on any error.

There is no need to catch any exception here, because we cannot usefully do anything with the exception. I would expect the exception to be handled somewhere higher up in the calling chain, e.g., where it might be logged and a friendly error message displayed to the user.

To conclude--the Microsoft sample code in the documentation is not always the best.

Answer (score 2):

A rollback of a transaction will undo anything that you did as a part of that transaction. So if you start a transaction, insert a few records into a table, do an update of a record and that update fails the rollback would remove the inserted records as well.

Comment: I understand the goal of the rollback function. What I didn't understand is why does it have to be called IF we know that the commit operation failed. If the commit fails, none of those changes should have happened in the table in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively check out [system.transactions.transactionscope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netframework-4.8)

it can be used inside a Using and if not completed will rollback without the need for a rollback command.

Comment: I'll look into that!

Answer (score 1):

You have to end the transaction with either rollback or commit. If the commit fails you have to rollback, so that the transaction isn't left open, which can naturally cause a multitude of problems.

Comment: I'm guessing that's the reason why it is best to use the `Using` directive ! Thanks!